# Form submissions including HTML in email notifications

Tags: forms, emails

I have a website where the core contact form is submitting the form markup along with the content.

So for example, this is in the email notifying the site owner of the submission:

```
<div class="field__label">The sender's name</div>

          <div class="field__item">Williamjeply</div>

      </div>
```

```
<div class="field__label">The sender's email</div>

          <div class="field__item">artofnegotiations@theonlinepublishers.com</div>

      </div>
```

```
<div class="field__label">Subject</div>

          <div class="field__item">How negotiations work! A must read  book</div>

      </div>
```

```
<div class="field__label">Message</div>

          <div class="field__item">LISTENEVERYHOW – How Negotiations  Work, is an easy-to-read book and pragmatic approach to get the best results  from a negotiation. It is adaptable in content and style – as a story book  for leisure readers, life skills manual for entrepreneurs and  professionals, or even as a business school handbook. <br />&#13;  <br />&#13; This book is written with clarity and easy eloquence of a man who knows what  he is talking about, telling captivating stories in well sequenced chapters  that all end with enticing nuggets. A rudiment skill in negotiation is  listening and the major themes of this book are reflective of the insights that  make the difference in negotiations. <br />&#13;  <br />&#13; You are one click away from having this excellent book for just $5.99  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08W5DMQV3/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_t1_6E8T8CE1VW6P49PPQF8F_nodl</div>

      </div>
```

I've made sure the permission allowing HTML emails is checked in the SMTP settings and there are no other obvious errors.
Does anyone have any clues why this is happening?
The issue queue doesn't provide much help on this.

The site was recently upgraded to 8.9.12 and is just using the core contact form.

Thanks in advance.

edit: apparently I'm using this module as well https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp

Comment: No, you're using more than just the core contact form if you have "SMTP settings" and if you have a setting that explicitly allows HTML in email. Please edit your post to say what email module you're using and how you've configured it.

Comment: You can't send HTML email with just Drupal core - you need a module that supports sending HTML mail, like Mime Mail or SwiftMailer. I'm pretty sure that the SMTP module just handles transport via SMTP and doesn't do anything to explicitly add HTML support. You haven't said whether this used to work for you and has now stopped working, or whether this is something that never worked? You haven't said if you're using any other module to handle HTML email. And you haven't said what versions of SMTP etc. you're using.

Comment: The "'Allow to send e-mails formatted as HTML'" setting in the SMTP module is poorly worded - checking that box just prevents HTML tags from being stripped out of the message body. But it does NOT add the mail headers needed to HTML mail. See the SMTP issue queue for more information: https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp/issues/2771559

Comment: @anonymous that was the problem. I figured it out over the weekend and came back to answer it for posterity. If you want the credit answer my question and I'll choose yours. Thanks.